# How can I combine rows based on a column value in google sheets

Tags: google-sheets

If I have a table like this:

[image]

How can I combine (by addition) the rows based on the values in column A so I get this table as a result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a `Pivot Table`. Please have a look https://support.google.com/docs/answer/1272900?hl=en&co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
={{A1:B1};query({A2:B},"select Col1,sum(Col2) where Col1<>'' group by Col1 order by sum(Col2) desc label sum(Col2) ''")}
```

OR

```
={{A1:B1};byrow(unique(filter(A2:A,A2:A<>"")),lambda(z,{z,sumif(A:A,z,B:B)}))}
```

[image]